# Make a class specific generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have created this Update method

```
 public void Update(Person updated)
   {
       var oldProperties = GetType().GetProperties();
       var newProperties = updated.GetType().GetProperties();
       for (var i = 0; i < oldProperties.Length; i++)
       {
           var oldval = oldProperties[i].GetValue(this, null);
           var newval = newProperties[i].GetValue(updated, null);
           if (oldval != newval)
               oldProperties[i].SetValue(this, newval, null);
       }
   }
```

What it does is comparing two Person objects and if there is any new values. It updates the original object. This works great, but being a lazy programmer, I would like it to be more reusable.

I would like it to work like this.

```
Person p1 = new Person(){Name = "John"};
Person p2 = new Person(){Name = "Johnny"};

p1.Update(p2);
p1.Name  => "Johnny"

Car c1 = new Car(){Brand = "Peugeot"};
Car c2 = new Car(){Brand = "BMW"};

c1.Update(c2);
c1.Brand => "BMW"

c1.Update(p1); //This should not be possible and result in an error.
```

I was thinking about using and Abstract Class to hold the Method and then use some Generic, but I don't know how to make it Class specific.

Comment: This code doesn't look class specific, the `Person` parameter could be changed to `object` and it would still work. Then you could put that method inside a class called `Updater` that has `Update(object left, object right)` and call `new Updater().Update(c1, c2);`. So in short, generics are not necessarily required at the moment. [Ask and you shall receive](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11757199/358221).

Comment: Note that your oldval != newval is **not robust**; don't use that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   public static void Update(object original, object updated)
   {
       var oldProperties = original.GetType().GetProperties();
       var newProperties = updated.GetType().GetProperties();
       for (var i = 0; i < oldProperties.Length; i++)
       {
           var oldval = oldProperties[i].GetValue(original, null);
           var newval = newProperties[i].GetValue(updated, null);
           if (!Equals(oldval,newval))
               oldProperties[i].SetValue(original, newval, null);
       }
   }
```

or if you want to ensure the same type:

```
   public static void Update<T>(T original, T updated)
   {
       var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
       for (var i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
       {
           var oldval = properties[i].GetValue(original, null);
           var newval = properties[i].GetValue(updated, null);
           if (!Equals(oldval,newval))
               properties[i].SetValue(original, newval, null);
       }
   }
```

Comment: @Pondidum I think a large proportion of his answer was a simply copy/paste from the OP :-P

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth so was mine :D

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a little flaw, in the fact that if you don't enforce that the two objects are effectively of the *exact same* type, they may not have the same properties and you would face errors.

A generic method like this should operate correctly on almost anything, as long as it's a `class` (that's what the constraint `where T: class` is there for: if it's not a class you're passing, code won't compile).

```
static void Update<T>(T original, T updated) where T : class
{
    var Properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in Properties)
    {
        var oldval = property.GetValue(original, null);
        var newval = property.GetValue(updated, null);
        if (oldval != newval) property.SetValue(original, newval, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Good catch on the class only marker, might want to explain why though.

Comment: To be honest, it's due to the title: "class specific" lead me to throw that in, I didn't really think it through.

Comment: *Lucky* catch then, it doesn't work on `struct` because of two reasons 1) they are currently passed by value so the caller won't see reflected changes, 2) if you specify `ref T original` in order to solve 1, the call to `property.SetValue(original...` boxes a copy of the `struct` so again the changes are not visible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern:

```
interface IUpdateable
{
void Update(IUpdateable updated)
}

public void Update<T>(T updated) where T:IUpdateable
{
...
...
}
```

Comment: This pattern would be correct if each class wanting to use `Update` needed to expose something that `Update` needs. As it stands, there is nothing other than the members of `object` that `Update` needs so this isn't required yet.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - You are right. The OP could just change the parameter type to 'object' and it would work for any type.